# Django Creating A Dynamic XML Sitemap That Updates Every Day

Tags: python, django, sitemap

How do I implement a dynamic sitemap in Django that updates itself based on newly added courses and lessons as well as all other static links?

The dynamic links that constantly get added or edited from admin are courses and lessons slugs are using this format:

domain.com/courses/courses/course_slug/lesson_slug

Directory Structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTW76.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzTrI.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2VH4.jpg

Updated Memberships urls.py:

https://dpaste.de/mT0d

Updated Courses urls.py code:

https://dpaste.de/6d54

Updated Project settings.py and urls.py:

https://dpaste.de/KpCc

All other code:

https://github.com/danialbagheri/video-membership

Here are all of the static links:

/

/courses/

/about/

/contact/

/memberships/

/memberships/profile/

/termsofservice/

/privacypolicy/

/memberships/payment/

And all of the allauth ones.

I have successfully gotten the sitemaps to load and it contains the Course and Lesson dynamic objects but still need to add in memberships links, static templates and allauth (not sure how to do that):

https://dpaste.de/Ef1D

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Django comes with [sitemap framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/) - you can use it to build xml sitemap for your website.

Comment: @Gasanov I looked through that link but I am confused still. I especially do not know what to do since I have 2 different apps with their own set of urls and also the allauth ones.

Comment: Did you at least tried it? Paste your code and we can try to find why it's not working. Everything you need to do to build sitemap is in django docs with a pretty great explanation.

Comment: @Gasanov I got to about 5 minutes in that youtube video where my sitemap.xml was not working. Maybe I put it in the files in the wrong place? I also tried this video but it was hard to follow because his app is very specific. https://youtu.be/U1f4QTyJBTs. I will continue to look through the docs also.

Comment: @Gasanov I tried doing what this link https://overiq.com/django-1-10/creating-sitemaps-in-django/ suggests but when I navigate to sitemap.xml I get a 404 not found error Raised by: courses.views.CourseDetailView

Comment: Edit your question to include how did you implement sitemaps, with full traceback of error. Make sure you have `DEBUG=True` in settings.

Comment: @Gasanov The question has been edited. Check the dpaste link at the bottom. Made some progress but now I need to connect everything else together. I got all the dynamic ones now I guess I only need the static ones.

Comment: Apparently there are no problems and you doing fine on your own. Great job!

Comment: @Gasanov I was until I could not figure out how to connect to the other static links and allauth ones. Can you help me with those?

Comment: Sure. [Here's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-for-static-views). Define each static link in `items` method and define `location` as `reverse()` to fetch proper link for each item.

Comment: @Gasanov I tried doing this and I am getting NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml/
Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
https://dpaste.de/mQSZ

Comment: Not 100% sure, but try `'home:home'` instead. Looks like you using `namespace`, so your `reverse` name should include it as well.

Comment: @Gasanov thank you I was able to get all of the static links except for the allauth ones. How would I get those? I tried the namespace convention - 'accounts:login' as well as just 'accounts' by itself and no success. Also I am not sure if there is one for the memberships 3d secure page since that is a redirect or memberships:update-transactions (this one the subscription_id always changes -> memberships/update-transactions/subscription_id

Comment: They have different names, check out [allauth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html). For example `account_login`. Do you need 3d secure pages in your xml sitemap? Those pages are usually not desired to be parsed by robots and as such not included in sitemap.

Comment: @Gasanov I got the allauth links in the sitemaps now. It would be nice to include the 3d secure page how would I do that? Do you mean the 3d secure pages or the allauth links are usually not desired in the sitemap?

Comment: Sitemap should include links that you want robots to see (such as google search engine). You probably want robots to see auth links (such as register/login pages). You probably don't want robots to see auto generated links to confirm user identities.